# Why is $\left(\frac{6}{-2}\right)^{1+2i}$ not equal to $\frac{6^{1+2i}}{(-2)^{1+2i}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is not a homework problem (I'm $75$ years old & retired). I'm stumped. When I use the following Law of Powers:

$$\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^x = \frac{a^x}{b^x} \tag1$$

and set $a = -6, b = 2$, and $x = 1+2i$, I obtain

$$\left(\frac{-6}{2}\right)^{1+2i} = \frac{(-6)^{1+2i}}{(2)^{1+2i}} \tag2$$
$$0.0033−0.0045i  =  0.0033−0.0045i $$

Evaluating Eq. $(2)$ I obtain the values shown just below Eq. (2) which seem correct. Now when I set $a = 6$, and $b = -2$, I obtain the following Eq. $(3)$.

$$\left(\frac{6}{-2}\right)^{1+2i} = \frac{6^{1+2i}}{(-2)^{1+2i}} \tag3$$
$$0.0033 - 0.0045i = 941.8 - 1301.4i$$

But when I evaluate Eq. $(3)$ I obtain the values shown just below Eq. $(3)$ which implies that Eq. $(3)$ is not valid. Can someone tell me why Eq. $(3)$ seems to be invalid? Thanks.

Comment: Complex exponents don't work the same real-valued ones do.

Comment: @SeanRoberson is right, the nature of complex exponentiation is much more subtle and involves multivalued functions and choosing branches and such.  I will add that while I don't know what software you are using to evaluate these, I'm somewhat surprised that the left hand side of (2) differs from the left hand side of (3), as the parentheses suggest each should first be simplified to $(-3)^{1+2i}$.  But I don't ever use software to play around with complex exponents so not sure if anything is actually amiss.  Might be worth double checking those numbers.

Comment: Read the complete formulation of law $(1)$.  It  has some conditions on $a, b$ and $x$.  We have many, many questions like this in this group; a common one is $$\left(\frac{1}{-1}\right)^{1/2} \ne \frac{(1)^{1/2}}{(-1)^{1/2}}$$

Comment: @ M W: My mistake. The numbers that should be just below Eq. (2) are: 0.0033−0.0045i  =  0.0033−0.0045i. I’ve corrected by original post. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

In general, $a^x$ is defined for $a$ a nonnegative number and $x$ a real number. We can extend this construction to complex numbers $z,w$ by defining
$$z^w := e^{w \log(z)}.$$
Where $\log$ is the principal branch of the complex logarithm, defined as $$\log(re^{i\theta}) = i \theta + \ln(|r|)$$
where $r > 0$ is a positive number, and $\theta$ is a real number. I use $\ln$ to refer to the natural logarithm that takes a positive number as input.

We can say that if $z,w$ are real numbers, everything is fine. When we move to complex numbers, things get worse because we have to deal with branch cuts of the complex logarithm.

$$(-3)^{1+2i} = e^{(1+2i)\log(-3)} = e^{(1+2i)(\ln(3) + \pi i)}.$$
This could potentially be bad, but let's see where it goes.

$$6^{1+2i} = e^{(1+2i)\ln(6)}.$$
$$(-2)^{1+2i} = e^{(1+2i)\log(-2)} = e^{(1+2i)(\ln(2) + \pi i)}.$$
The problem with this approach is what happens when we divide and assume that we can use our normal exponent rules:
$$\frac{6^{1+2i}}{(-2)^{1+2i}} = e^{(1+2i)(\ln(6)-(\ln(2) {\color{red}{+\pi i}}))} = e^{(1+2i)(\ln(3)\color{red}{-\pi i})} \neq 3^{1+2i} = e^{(1+2i)(\ln(3)+\color{red}{\pi i})}.$$

If we do the algebra on the left hand and right hand side, we get
$$(6)^{1+2i}/(-2)^{1+2i}=e^{(\ln(3)+2\pi) + i(2\ln(3) + \pi))} \neq e^{(\ln(3)-2\pi) + i(2\ln(3)-\pi)}= (-3)^{1+2i}.$$

In short, the complex logarithm does not play nicely with nonpositive numbers in the base (especially not complex numbers, and division as well): in fact the magnitude of the complex number changes. A quick check in google's calculator suggests that this is what is happening under the hood (look at the magnitudes.)

You should basically avoid using power rules at all costs and attempt to work with the complex numbers in polar form.

Another example of why complex logarithms are scary is in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R476CTKUIr4&ab_channel=MindYourDecisions

Comment: @1mdlrrjcmed Thanks. How coincidental. Your posted Youtube link is the same video that caused me to start studying all of this!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're confusing real exponents with the complex ones..

To give a short description,

Complex exponents and real exponents are both mathematical concepts related to raising a number to a certain power, but they have some key differences due to the nature of complex numbers.

-When dealing with real numbers, the concept of exponentiation is straightforward. If you have a real number "$a$" and you raise it to a real exponent "$b$", the result is simply a real number. For example, if you have $2^3$, the result is $8$, which is a real number.

-In contrast to real numbers, Complex numbers consist of a real part and an imaginary part, usually denoted as "$a + bi$", where "$a$" and "$b$" are real numbers and "$i$" is the imaginary unit ($\sqrt{-1}$). When dealing with complex numbers, the concept of exponentiation becomes more intricate.

Euler's formula is a fundamental result that relates complex exponentials to trigonometric functions:

$$e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i \cdot \sin(x)$$

*where "$e$" is the base of the natural logarithm, "$i$" is the imaginary unit, "$x$" is a real number, and "$\cos$" and "$\sin$" are trigonometric functions.*

When you raise the base "$e$" to a complex exponent "$ix$", you get a complex number that has both a real and imaginary part, as shown in the formula above. The magnitude of this complex number is always 1, because of the trigonometric identities involved.

In summary, the main difference between complex exponents and real exponents is that raising a real number to a real exponent yields another real number, while raising the base "$e$" to a complex exponent generates a complex number with both real and imaginary parts. Complex exponentiation is intimately connected to trigonometric functions through Euler's formula...